# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^3+x-2}{x^3-x^2-x+1}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^3+x-2}{x^3-x^2-x+1}$$

In the above question, I tried to solve using factorization. Since putting $x$ as $1$ gives an indeterminate form, therefore, $(x-1)$ is a factor of both numerator and denominator.

After the factors cancel out and putting the limit, what I get is $0$ in the denominator. I haven't thought of the possibility of "infinite" as the answer though.

I tried L'Hospital's rule too, same result. :(

Comment: What's wrong with an "infinite" (more formally, "undefined") answer? If you plot the function, you'll see an asymptote at $x=1$.

Comment: The limit does not exist.

Comment: Got it @Blue  thanks for the help..

Comment: After simplications, let $x=y+1$ to get $\frac{y^2+3 y+4}{y (y+2)}$ and use the long division.

Comment: @ShrishBhargav, could you read my answer? Tell me if you like it.

Comment: @Angelo yes, thanks a lot. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @ShrishBhargav, you are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does not exist the limit $\;\lim\limits_{x\to1}\dfrac{x^3+x-2}{x^3-x^2-x+1}\;$ but we can calculate the following two limits :

$\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\dfrac{x^3\!+\!x\!-\!2}{x^3\!-\!x^2\!-\!x\!+\!1}=-\infty\;$ and $\;\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}\dfrac{x^3\!+\!x\!-\!2}{x^3\!-\!x^2\!-\!x\!+\!1}=+\infty\,.$

Now, we will calculate the first limit.

$\begin{align}\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\dfrac{x^3+x-2}{x^3-x^2-x+1}&=\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\dfrac{(x-1)(x^2+x+2)}{(x+1)(x-1)^2}=\\[3pt]&=\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}\dfrac{x^2+x+2}{(x+1)(x-1)}=\dfrac4{0^-}=-\infty\,.\end{align}$

Analogously, we can calculate the second limit.

Here is the graph of the function $\,f(x)=\dfrac{x^3+x-2}{x^3-x^2-x+1}\,.$

[image]